# What does the third number in a NFL team's record stand for?

Tags: american-football, statistics, nfl

What does the third number in a NFL team's record stand for?

Answer (score 6):

Ties. This happens when both teams end overtime with the same score.

The [NFL Overtime Rules](http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-overtime-rules/) explicitly state this:

> If the score is still tied at the end of the overtime period, the
>   result of the game will be recorded as a tie.

NFL.com [standings](http://www.nfl.com/standings?category=div&season=2016-REG&split=Overall) label the third column **T**.

Answer (score 3):

In American sports, such as American football played in the NFL, the [three numbers generally represent wins-losses-ties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_percentage). So a record of 36-20-1 means 36 wins, 20 losses and 1 tie. The exception to this is ice hockey in the NHL, in which the third number refers to overtime losses (since ties are no longer possible).

[As shown on this Toronto FC supporters' forum post](http://forums.redpatchboys.ca/showthread.php?31735-Win-Draw-Loss-or-Win-Loss-Draw-Pick-one-already!) (an association football club in the MLS), this may lead to confusion for followers of European sports, as in Europe, the record is normally given as wins, draws and losses - i.e. a record of 50-5-40 means 50 wins, 5 draws and 40 losses.

[Note that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(draw)) in European sports, the preferred term is *draw* (except in cricket, where both terms are used and have distinct meanings), while in American sports, the preferred term is *tie*.

Comment: Not true.  In hockey, the third number is OTL (overtime loss).

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - if you can provide a source for this, I'll edit it in to my answer (or you can feel free to make an edit).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(ice_hockey), look for Team Stat